# Сбор информации от пользователей

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Всем привет. Стоит задача, ежедневно собирать информацию о проделанной работе за сутки от 10 человек. На данный момент это реализовано через Гугл таблицы и сайд бар. Строка записи в таблицу выглядит вот так:
[Дата работы][Район][Нас. Пункт][Тип работы][Кол-во][Примечание]. Появилась потребность получать более конкретную информацию: Адрес, Диаметр, Материал,Организация и т.п. Вопрос: Есть ли какие-то сервисы, которые в которых можно реализовать данный функционал ? Дабы не изобретать заново велосипед в Гугл таблицах

Comment: Т.е. если я правильно понял, сегодня вам каждый ваш агент присылает EXCEL-таблицу, которые вы у себя компонуете в единую таблицу с которой далее работаете? Или вообще работаете в одной таблице google sheets. Теперь вместо 6 столбцов в этой таблице  должно быть 12? Тогда в чем вопрос, чем вас не устраивает тот подход что и был? Ну, если очень хочется новшеств, попробуйте делать через Google-Forms. Поясните, что вас заставляет искать какой-то сервис, тогда можно будет ответить что-то более конкретное. (И причем тут тег "статистика", кстати?)

Comment: @passant на данный момент все работают в одной гугл таблице. Вопрос заключается в том, чтобы не  верстать новый html виджет для заполнения таблицы. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед есть ли какие либо сервисы по сбору данных ? Гугл формы не подходят по причине ограниченного функционала

Comment: https://www.livebusiness.ru/tags/sozdanie_web_form/ смотрите, выбирайте. Только чудес не бывает.  Эти сервисы полезны, когда вы в день пишете по 5 опросников. А когда раз в год к вашей форме надо добавить три новых поля -  то тут лучшее решение  - ручками.  Вопрос про тег "статистика" - остался открытым. Дождетесь, что забанят из за неверного применения тегов.

Comment: Считаю, что заданный вопрос - ["абстрактный и дискуссионный"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Требуемая функциональность не описана, мнения могут быть разные...